# Want to dispay one to many records as a single row using android and sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have three table below:

orderMaster:

```
orderNo | status |contactId
--------+--------+---------
100     |Pending |1
200     |Pending |2
300     |Pending |3
```

orderShirtPant:

```
orderNo | ShirtorPant |Quantity
--------+-------------+--------
100     |Shirt        |2
100     |Pant         |3
200     |Shirt        |1
200     |Pant         |3
300     |Shirt        |2
```

contacts:

```
contactId | Name
----------+-----------
1         | Mahesh
2         | Anil
3         | Ramesh
```

Want output Like below:

```
Name    |orderNo| orderDetails 
--------+-------+-------------
Mahesh  |100    |2 Shirt, 3 Pant    
Anil    |200    |1 Shirt, 3 Pant    
Ramesh  |300    |2 Shirt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query to get your result

```
select Name,group_concat(Quantity ||' '|| orderShirtPant.ShirtorPant),orderShirtPant.orderNo from contacts,orderShirtPant,orderMaster where contacts.contactId =orderMaster.contactId and orderMaster.orderNo =orderShirtPant.orderNo group by Name;
```

Comment: Thanks It's working